# Why can't I compile the HTML platform of my libgdx project?

Tags: java, gwt, gradle, build, libgdx

why can't I compile the HTML platform of my libgdx project?

I'm trying to compile it with the gradle task html:dist, but I get the following error, while gradle is trying to compile it with GWT:

```
00:00:29.357 :html:compileGwt
00:00:29.358 [ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
00:00:29.358 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown property: jre.checks.type
00:00:29.358    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.Properties.setProperties(Properties.java:132)
00:00:29.358    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompilerContext$Builder.build(CompilerContext.java:46)
00:00:29.369    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:193)
00:00:29.369    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:155)
00:00:29.369    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:144)
00:00:29.369    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:118)
00:00:29.369    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
00:00:29.369    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
00:00:29.369    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:125)
00:00:29.531 :html:compileGwt FAILED
```

The other projects/platforms (Desktop and Android) are compiling without any error

The complete console-output:

```
00:00:01.900 Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).
00:00:04.651 Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
00:00:17.334 :html:clean UP-TO-DATE
00:00:17.336 :html:addSource
00:00:17.465 :core:compileJavawarning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
00:00:17.465 1 warning
00:00:17.668 
00:00:17.669 :core:processResources UP-TO-DATE
00:00:17.669 :core:classes
00:00:17.669 :core:jar
00:00:19.255 :html:compileJava
00:00:19.257 Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx-backend-gwt/1.9.4/gdx-backend-gwt-1.9.4.pom
00:00:19.332 Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx-box2d-gwt/1.9.4/gdx-box2d-gwt-1.9.4.pom
00:00:19.953 Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx-backend-gwt/1.9.4/gdx-backend-gwt-1.9.4.jar
00:00:20.095 Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx-backend-gwt/1.9.4/gdx-backend-gwt-1.9.4-sources.jar
00:00:20.192 Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx/1.9.4/gdx-1.9.4-sources.jar
00:00:20.215 Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx-box2d/1.9.4/gdx-box2d-1.9.4-sources.jar
00:00:20.379 Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx-box2d-gwt/1.9.4/gdx-box2d-gwt-1.9.4-sources.jar
00:00:21.878 warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
00:00:22.007 1 warning
00:00:22.018 :html:processResources UP-TO-DATE
00:00:29.357 :html:compileGwt
00:00:29.358 [ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
00:00:29.358 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown property: jre.checks.type
00:00:29.358    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.Properties.setProperties(Properties.java:132)
00:00:29.358    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompilerContext$Builder.build(CompilerContext.java:46)
00:00:29.369    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:193)
00:00:29.369    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:155)
00:00:29.369    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:144)
00:00:29.369    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:118)
00:00:29.369    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
00:00:29.369    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
00:00:29.369    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:125)
00:00:29.531 :html:compileGwt FAILED
00:00:29.911 
00:00:29.911 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
00:00:29.912 
00:00:29.914 * What went wrong:
00:00:29.914 Execution failed for task ':html:compileGwt'.
00:00:29.914 > Process 'command '/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk-8u112/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
00:00:29.914 
00:00:29.914 * Try:
00:00:29.915 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
00:00:29.915 
00:00:29.928 BUILD FAILED
00:00:29.928 
00:00:29.928 Total time: 28.819 secs
00:00:34.912 Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
00:00:34.912 Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
00:00:34.969 Archiving artifacts
00:00:35.171 Recording fingerprints
00:00:35.593 Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: What version of libGDX and GWT are you using? Could you include your project and html gradle files?
"

Comment: Hi John I'm using libGDX 1.9.4 and just found out, that I need to use gwt 2.6.0. I'm now using at and the project is building without errors. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!